# gcc unable to get file which is passed in include directory argument

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors, cygwin, mingw

I've installed win-builds from http://win-builds.org on windows at c:\cygwins directory.
Now when compiling any elementary or gtk  code, gcc is throwing error that it's cannot find the

`gtk_test.c:1:21: fatal error: gtk/gtk.h: No such file or directory
 #include <gtk/gtk.h>
                     ^`

or

`button_example_01.c:1:24: fatal error: Elementary.h: No such file or directory
 #include <Elementary.h>
                        ^`

I've tried switching the tool-chain as suggested in win-builds documentation 'source /opt/windows_64/bin/win-builds-switch ' mentioned at http://win-builds.org/1.5.0/msys-cygwin.html#_change_toolchain_on_the_fly

In case of `Elementary.h` error I can find this file 
`$ find /opt/windows_32/ -name 'Elementary.h'
/opt/windows_32/include/elementary-1/Elementary.h`

Also when I compile the program by providing the cflags and libs value returned from pkg-config, this file path is there as

`/opt/windows_32/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-gcc -o button_example_01 button_example_01.c -I/opt/windows_32/include/elementary-1/ -I/opt/windows_32/include/efl-1 -I/opt/windows_32/include/ecore-win32-1 -I/opt/windows_32/include/efl-1 -I/opt/windows_32/include/ethumb-client-1 -I/opt/windows_32/include/efl-1 -I/opt/windows_32/include/ethumb-1 -I/opt/windows_32/include/efl-1 -I/opt/windows_32/include/edje-1 -I/opt/windows_32/include/efl-1 -I/opt/windows_32/include/embryo-1 -I/opt/windows_32/include/efl-1 -I/opt/windows_32/include/ecore-imf-evas-1 -I/opt/windows_32/include/efl-1 -I/opt/windows_32/include/ecore-evas-1 -I/opt/windows_32/include/efl-1 -I/opt/windows_32/include/ecore-input-evas-1 -I/opt/windows_32/include/efl-1 -I/opt/windows_32/include/emotion-1 -I/opt/windows_32/include/efl-1 -I/opt/windows_32/include/evas-1 -I/opt/windows_32/include/libpng14 -I/opt/windows_32/include/harfbuzz -I/opt/windows_32/include/fribidi -I/opt/windows_32/include -I/opt/windows_32/include/freetype2 -I/opt/windows_32/include -I/opt/windows_32/include/freetype2 -I/opt/windows_32/include -I/opt/windows_32/include/efl-1 -I/opt/windows_32/include/ecore-imf-1 -I/opt/windows_32/include/efl-1 -I/opt/windows_32/include/ecore-input-1 -I/opt/windows_32/include/efl-1 -I/opt/windows_32/include/efreet-1 -I/opt/windows_32/include/efl-1 -I/opt/windows_32/include/efreet-1 -I/opt/windows_32/include/efl-1 -I/opt/windows_32/include/efreet-1 -I/opt/windows_32/include/efl-1 -I/opt/windows_32/include/eldbus-1 -I/opt/windows_32/include/dbus-1.0 -I/opt/windows_32/lib/dbus-1.0/include -I/opt/windows_32/include/efl-1 -I/opt/windows_32/include/ecore-file-1 -I/opt/windows_32/include/efl-1 -I/opt/windows_32/include/ecore-con-1 -I/opt/windows_32/include -I/opt/windows_32/include/efl-1 -I/opt/windows_32/include/eio-1 -I/opt/windows_32/include/efl-1 -I/opt/windows_32/include/eet-1 -I/opt/windows_32/include -I/opt/windows_32/include/efl-1 -I/opt/windows_32/include/ecore-1 -I/opt/windows_32/include/efl-1 -I/opt/windows_32/include/eo-1 -I/opt/windows_32/include/efl-1 -I/opt/windows_32/include/eina-1 -I/opt/windows_32/include/eina-1/eina -I/opt/windows_32/include/efl-1 -I/opt/windows_32/include/evil-1 -L/opt/windows_32/lib -lelementary -lm -leina -lpthread -leet -levas -lecore -lecore_evas -lecore_file -lecore_input -ledje -leo -lethumb_client -lemotion -lecore_imf -lecore_con -leldbus -lefreet -lefreet_mime -lefreet_trash -leio -levil -lecore_win32 -lole32 -lgdi32 -lethumb_client -lethumb -ledje -lm -lembryo -lm -lecore_imf_evas -lecore_evas -lecore_input_evas -lemotion -levas -ljpeg  -lm -lpng14 -lz -lharfbuzz -lfribidi -lfontconfig -lexpat -lfreetype -lexpat -lfreetype -lpng14 -llua -lm -lecore_imf -lecore_input -lefreet -lefreet_mime -lefreet_trash -leldbus -ldbus-1 -lpthread -lws2_32 -lecore_file -lecore_con -lm -lcares -lws2_32 -leio -lm -leet -lm -ljpeg -lz -lecore -lm -lintl -L/opt/windows_32/lib -leo -leina -lpthread -lm  -liconv -levil
button_example_01.c:1:24: fatal error: Elementary.h: No such file or directory
 #include "Elementary.h"
                        ^
compilation terminated.`

What I guess is that gcc does not interpret the cygwin /opt/... paths.
I will appreciate if anyone can help me fixing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

**fatal error: 'Elementary.h' file not found**  seems to be a common problem. Thanks to Jeff's answer to this:   http://forums.bodhilinux.com/index.php?/topic/12061-answered-help-compiling-elementary-code-examples/

This answer helped me also with getting Elementary to compile on BodhiLinux. When I tried it on FreeBSD I also had the same error despite that I did have an Elementary.h installed in the system.
I got the idea to check the dependencies for efl at freebsd's page here:

https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/ports.cgi?query=enlightenment&stype=all

I went through each dependency for efl-1.18.4 and found I had to add:
autoconf, automake, bullet, gmake, gmp, libdvdcss, libtool, pkgconf, and png.
This got the following working for cc and clang:

```
cc getstarted.c -o GetStarted `pkgconf elementary --cflags --libs`
```

If you are having problems check for dependencies. In my case I think pkgconf did the job.